# Install Android Studio on existing IntelliJ Ultimate installation

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I have a licensed IntelliJ Idea Ultimate.
How can I install Android Studio on top of my existing installation?

The new bundle Google gave us, contains SDK + the community edition of IntelliJ + Android Studio.

Can i install it, as we do with Eclipse and ADT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fow now, we cant.**

JetBrains replied to me on Google+.

Android Studio is currently only  in the IntelliJ EAP 13 (Early Release Preview).
After that, some periodic builds will released, maybe some Release Candidates(RC's)

So all we can do for now is download the EAP 13, and send them feedback, so final release v.13 comes out faster!

Comment: Now that Android Studio is released does anyone know if this is still true? http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html